# chain rule for integration

Tags: integration

How can I apply the chain rule to this integral

$$\int (1-6x)^{-\frac{1}2} dx$$

I would say I could make this:

${{\frac{1}2}{(1-6x)^{\frac{1}2}}\over {\frac{1}2}}$

And then simplify from there but I suspect there is more to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-6x}}$$

Substitute $\color{green}\nu:=1-6x$

so $d\nu=-6dx$

therfore $dx=\color{blue}{-\frac{d\nu}{6}}$

so we have :

$$=\int\frac{\color{blue}{-\frac{d\nu}{6}}}{\sqrt{\color{green}\nu}}$$

$$=-\frac 1 6 \int \frac{d\nu}{\sqrt{\nu}}=-\frac 1 6 \int \left(\nu^{-1/2}\right)d\nu=\frac{-\frac 1 6 \nu ^{(-1/2+1)}}{1/2}+\mathcal C=-\frac 1 6\frac{\nu^{1/2}}{\frac 1 2}+\mathcal C=-\frac{\sqrt{\nu}}{3}+\mathcal C$$

Set back $\nu=1-6x$

$$\color{red}{=-\frac 1 3\sqrt{1-6x}+\mathcal C}$$

Comment: could you please explain the steps.  that would be very helpful

Comment: Yes, I will edit

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-6x}}$$

You also can substitute

$\nu:=\sqrt{1-6x}$ and $d\nu=-\frac{6}{2\sqrt{1-6x}}dx$ so $dx=-d\nu \frac{\sqrt{1-6x}}{3}=-d\nu \frac{\nu}{3}$

$$=-\int\frac{\nu}{3 \nu}d\nu=-\int\frac 1 3 d\nu=-\frac {\nu} 3 +\mathcal C=\color{red}{-\frac{\sqrt{1-6x}}{3}+\mathcal C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=1-6x$ so $du=-6dx$ so the integral becomes $\int{-u^{-1/2}}du/6$   $=-2u^{1/2}du/6+c=-(1-6x)^{1/2}/3+c$